# HTML does not respect .CSS file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to load html page in WKWebView which is linked  to external javascript and css files. My web view shows me the html page but it does not seem like that its respecting css file values. Can anyone please suggest me as to what am I doing wrong here. Following my code to add html page in WKWebView:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html");
    let htmlString = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

    self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath));

  }
```

Also, here is the project structure where .css, .js and .html files re added.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Beta 4.  I have the same issue but so far my research has not turned up a solution. Hope the next beta resolves the many wkwebview issues floating around.

Comment: Check the answer in this link. It has a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922628/swift-apply-local-css-to-web-view

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `WKWebView` renders page content inside a sandbox process that cannot access files in your application bundle. This effectively means that `file://` URLs do not work.

I ended up including a [small web server](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) in my application to make it easier to serve content to the `WKWebView`.