# SWIFT - Loading local CSS file

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to add some local css to my webview but it seems that I have a problem with the css file in my app :

[image]

Nothing happens when I try to load the css from the local css file but when I replace '%@' by a online css file it works fine.

Thank you for your help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.delegate = self

        let html: String! = "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"postcontent\"><h1>Hello</h1></div></body></html>"

        webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "styles", ofType: "css")

        let javaScriptStr: NSString = "var link = document.createElement('link'); link.href = '%@'; link.rel = 'stylesheet'; document.head.appendChild(link)"
        let javaScripthPath = NSString(format: javaScriptStr, path!)
        webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: javaScripthPath as String)
        print(javaScripthPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this and see if it helps. [Swift - Apply local css to be view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922628/swift-apply-local-css-to-web-view)

Comment: I have already checked that post that is why our code is pretty similar but it seems it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML file is loaded from a string, so it's loaded into a web view that can't access files on the file system (probably due to the Same Origin Policy that browsers implement). It can only access resources similarly injected in via `loadHTMLString`.

If you want to use local CSS, load your HTML from a file instead of a string. This will give the web view access to the CSS if it's in the same directory.

Here is a demo, first, the HTML is now a file.

[image]

Then, your code can look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.delegate = self

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "app", ofType: "html")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        webview.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "styles", ofType: "css")!

        let javaScriptStr = "var link = document.createElement('link'); link.href = '\(path)'; link.rel = 'stylesheet'; document.head.appendChild(link)"
        webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: javaScriptStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for your answer. It works well with the html file. But the html part will be dynamic and get by database call so any other way to do it without creating a file each time ?

Comment: The alternative would be to also inject your CSS in as a string, that will probably work because they'll be in the same "domain".